# GCM PHP - Passing Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to push a two-dimensional array to device. However, I found that GCM only able to send a single array at one time.

I am looking for a solution to overcome this issue. Because I think it is not practical to keep pushing information one by one.

**Below are two different scenarios**

*Single Dimension Array(Which is successfully to push to device)*

```
Array
(
    [pump_name] => LEVO 92
    [pump_price] => 2.5
)
1
{"multicast_id":8959934119853137719,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1445482576757470%9dde29c5f9fd7ecd"}]}
Array
(
    [pump_name] => LEVO 95
    [pump_price] => 3
)
1
{"multicast_id":6988128903201803494,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1445482576797158%9dde29c5f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

*Two Dimension Array(Which is fail to push to device)*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pump_name] => LEVO 92
            [pump_price] => 2.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pump_name] => LEVO 95
            [pump_price] => 3
        )

)
1
Field "data" must be a JSON array: [{"pump_name":"LEVO 92","pump_price":"2.5"},{"pump_name":"LEVO 95","pump_price":"3"}]
```

**Codes (I split it into two parts)**

*Pump Price Function*

```
function pump_price() {

    global $wpdb;

    $result = array();
    $temp_result = array();
    $counter = 1;

    $rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE %s", 'pump_price_list_%', 'pump_%'));

    if($rows) :
        foreach($rows AS $row) :
            if($counter % 2 == 0) :

                // Store Value Into Temporary Array
                $temp_result["pump_price"] = $row->meta_value;

                array_push($result, $temp_result);

                // Unset Temporary Array
                unset($temp_result);
                $temp_result = array();

            else :

                $temp_result['pump_name'] = $row->meta_value;

            endif;
            $counter++;
        endforeach;
    endif;

    sendGoogleCloudMessage($result);

}
```

*GCM Function*

```
function sendGoogleCloudMessage($result) {

    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'MY-API-KEY' );

    $registrationIds = array('MY-DEVICE-ID');

    $headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $fields = array (
        'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
        'data'              => $result
    );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $results = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    echo $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending 2 JSONs and thats the problem. You can combine them into one like this:

```
{  
    "array1": {
               "pump_name":"LEVO 92",
               "pump_price":"2.5"
              },
    "array2": {
               "pump_name":"LEVO 95",
               "pump_price":"3"
              }
}
```

Then you have to spilt them client side

Comment: Thanks for replying! Let me give it a try. Get back to you later.

Comment: Hi @Ali, thank you for your suggestion. I managed to do it by adding a little thing inside my code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for those people who looking solution for this issue.

I managed to find a solution after referring to @Ali suggestion.

But there are some codes need to change before you can pass two-dimensional data or more. Please read the solution below.

**Solution**

*Convert your array into Object*

```
if($rows) :
    foreach($rows AS $row) :
        if($counter % 2 == 0) :

            // Store Value Into Temporary Array
            $temp_result["pump_price"] = $row->meta_value;

            array_push($result, (object)$temp_result);

            // Unset Temporary Array
            unset($temp_result);
            $temp_result = array();

        else :

            $temp_result['pump_name'] = $row->meta_value;

        endif;
        $counter++;
    endforeach;
endif;

sendGoogleCloudMessage((object)$result);
```

Please correct me if this is not an ideal solution.